# Изменить формат времени в DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Всем привет.

Для записей создаю дату.
С фронта приходит unixdate

На беке я эти принимаю вот так :

```
 DateTime d = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(request.CreateDate).DateTime.ToLocalTime();
        var utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(d, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

На выходе переменная utc имеет вид : 2022-08-09T14:22:27.211Z
А нужно ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ:СС
Если сделать utc.toString, то на выходе получаю именно то что надо. Но строку.
А мне нужен DateTime.
Как можно это сделать без перевода в строку ?

Пробовал так , но не получается

```
 var format = "dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss";
        var testString = utc.ToString();
        DateTime dt;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(utc.ToString(),
                               format,
                               null,
                               DateTimeStyles.None,
                               out dt);
```

Handler в котором обрабатываются данные и возращаются на бек:

```
public class CreateItemBlackListHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateItemBlackListCommand, Result<BlackListEntity>>
{
    readonly IRepository<BlackListEntity> _repository;
    public CreateItemBlackListHandler(
        IRepository<BlackListEntity> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Task<Result<BlackListEntity>> Handle(CreateItemBlackListCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        DateTime parsedDate;
        DateTime d = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(request.CreateDate).DateTime;
        var utc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(d, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var result = _repository.CreateAsync(new BlackListEntity()
        {
            Id = request.ItemId,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            MiddleName = request.MiddleName,
            CreateDate = utc,
            PhoneNumber = request.PhoneNumber,
        }, cancellationToken);
   
        return result;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Если вам нужно UTC, `.ToLocalTime();` уберите. С буквой Z должно быть UTC время, а у вас локальное. Из-за этого может начаться путаница. Что касается самого вопроса, то `ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ:СС` - это строка, а не дата. Как вы хотите получить строку, но не строку - непонятно. Переформулируйте вопрос, для чего это вам.

Comment: Второй раз вам метку с `asp` на `asp.net-core` правлю, как вы думаете, почему? Потому что это совершенно разные платформы и не стоит их путать.

Comment: @aepot я тут новичек, "+" я поставил на ответе, а про то что его еще нужно принять не знал :)
Исправил.
LocalTime убрал. 
Тоесть вернуть DateTime в нужном формате нельзя. 
Стало быть надо DateTime сохранять в БД как есть , а в нужный формат переводить в JS?

Comment: Так в JS передавайте его обратно так же как `timeStamp` числом, а на фронте уже на уровне браузера формируйте обратно из него `new Date(timeStamp)` и форматируйте как душе угодно яваскриптом. Либо передвайте как строку уже в нужном формате. Если решили передавать дату как число, а это единственный надежный способ, то используйте этот формат передачи данных в обе стороны.

Comment: @aepot звучит логично и достаточно просто :)
У меня просто в Entity моделяж уже дата как DateTime. И я возращаю эту модель.
Прикрепил к основному восту пример кода.

Comment: Если на бэке вам представление даты не нужно, вы можете легко заменить формат даты в базе на `long` (Int64) и не париться с преобразованиями. Пусть работа с датами будет полностью на фронте, серверу же легче, и в базе порядок, и нет проблем с часовыми поясами.